# Start job (with needs) after trigger job is completed (regardless the result, passed or failed)

Tags: gitlab-ci

I tried to use the `when` keyword for a job that needs another job. To execute that job after the other is completed.

I have the following configuration

[job1] - triggers a child-pipeline (depends) and fails if any job in the child pipeline is failed
[job2] - has configured `needs: job1` shall be executed once the trigger job [job1] is completed (regardless the result, passed or failed)

Unfortunately I was not successful using the `when` keyword:

- `when: on_success`: only starts if the trigger job is passed
- `when: always`: immediately starts regardless the trigger job
- `when: on_failure`: only starts if the trigger job is failed

How to achieve the decribed behaviour?

Example:
`job2` is executed after `job1` but `job4` not as `job3` is failing

```
job1:
  script:
    - echo "Execute some commands"
    - exit 0

job2:
  script:
    - echo "Execute some other commands"
  needs: ["job1"]
  rules:
    - exists:

job3:
  script:
    - echo "Execute some commands"
    - exit 1

job4:
  script:
    - echo "Execute some other commands"
  needs: ["job3"]
  rules:
    - exists:
```

One dirty work-around would be to add two equal jobs, one with "on_success" the other with "on_failure" and one of them will trigger. But this is really not what I intended.